# Postgresql: How can I inspect which arguments to a procedure have a default value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have defined a stored procedure in Postgresql:

```
create or replace function 
  test1(arg1 text, opt1 text default 'default value') 
  returns text as $$ select $1 || ' ' || $2; $$ language sql;
```

I would like to inspect this function definition to find out:

1. Which parameters have a default value
2. (bonus) What the default values are

I tried comparing `information_schema.parameters` records for the example:

```
select * from information_schema.parameters;
```

*(using `diff -y --suppress-common-lines`)*

```
-[ RECORD 4808 ]---------+----------------------- | -[ RECORD 4809 ]---------+-----------------------------------
ordinal_position         | 1                      | ordinal_position         | 2
parameter_name           | arg1                   | parameter_name           | opt1
dtd_identifier           | 1                      | dtd_identifier           | 2
```

The only place I have managed to find reference to the default value is in the `pg_proc` table:

```
select proargdefaults from pg_proc where proname = 'test1' ;

-[ RECORD 1 ]--+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
proargdefaults | ({CONST :consttype 25 :consttypmod -1 :constcollid 100 :constlen -1 :constbyval false :constisnull false :location 62 :constvalue 10 [ 40 0 0 0 119 105 98 98 108 101 ]})
```

That bit in square brackets at the end seems to contain the default in some kind of internal format:

*(using Python)*

```
>>> d="68 0 0 0 100 101 102 97 117 108 116 32 118 97 108 117 101"
>>> "".join([chr(int(a)) for a in d.split()])
'D\x00\x00\x00default value'
```

My question: Is there a better way to inspect this function to find out about default parameters?

**Update** I am looking for something that produces output like...

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+----------------------------
arg_index        | 1
arg_name         | arg1
arg_has_default  | f
arg_default_text | <null>
-[ RECORD 2 ]----+----------------------------
arg_index        | 2
arg_name         | opt1
arg_has_default  | t
arg_default_text | default value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the optional arguments from `pg_proc`, but you probably won't be able to parse their default values' expressions on PostgreSQL's side (because they can have different types).

```
select proargnames[pronargs-pronargdefaults+1:pronargs] optargnames,
       pg_get_expr(proargdefaults, 0) optargdefaults
from   pg_proc
where  proname = 'test1'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2931)

**EDIT**: found a way to easily parse the default values into a `json` value (keys are the argument names, values are their default values' json representation):

```
create or replace function proargdefaultsjson(proc pg_proc) returns json
language plpgsql
as $function$
declare
  expr_parsed record;
begin
  execute format(
    'select * from (values (%s)) v(%s)',
    pg_get_expr(proc.proargdefaults, 0),
    array_to_string(array(
      select quote_ident(n)
      from unnest(proc.proargnames[proc.pronargs-proc.pronargdefaults+1:proc.pronargs]) n
    ), ',')
  ) into expr_parsed;
  return row_to_json(expr_parsed);
end
$function$;
```

This function should work in PostgreSQL 9.2+: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/2503)

**EDIT 2**: you can achieve something similar with the [`hstore` module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html), if you return with `hstore(expr_parsed);` (this case you will end up with each default expression's text representation).

Comment: That solves point 1 to my satisfaction. Thanks very much! I have started a [new fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2962) to try to answer point 2.

Comment: Related thread on the [Postgresql mailing list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1356092400.25658.6.camel@vanquo.pezone.net)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pg_get_function_arguments()` to retrieve the definition of the parameters:

```
SELECT pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as parameters
FROM pg_proc p 
   JOIN pg_namespace n ON p.pronamespace = n.oid 
WHERE p.proname = 'test1' 
  AND n.nspname = 'public';
```

This will return `arg1 text, opt1 text DEFAULT 'default value'::text` for your example.

Comment: That is good but doesn't allow me to see which named arguments have default values without parsing the output somehow.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT A.ordinal_position AS seq
     , A.parameter_name
     , A.data_type
     , default_value
     , CASE
            WHEN position('NULL' in LTRIM(default_value)) > 0 THEN 'N' 
            ElSE 'Y'
       END AS defaultYN
FROM (
        SELECT routines.routine_name,
               parameters.*
        FROM   information_schema.routines
        LEFT JOIN information_schema.parameters ON routines.specific_name=parameters.specific_name
        WHERE routines.routine_name = 'yourProcName'
        ORDER BY routines.routine_name, parameters.ordinal_position
) A
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT unnest(optargnames) as parameter_name
             , unnest(string_to_array(optargdefaults, ', ')) as default_value
        FROM (
                SELECT proargnames[pronargs-pronargdefaults+1:pronargs] optargnames,
                       pg_get_expr(proargdefaults, 0) optargdefaults
                FROM   pg_catalog.pg_proc
                WHERE  proname = 'yourProcName'
         ) BBBB
) B
ON A.parameter_name  = B.parameter_name
```

[image]

Comment: i can't speak english
refer image plz

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    a.parameter_name,
    case when typeall is null
        then types
    else
        typeall
    end as  type,
    coalesce(a.parameter_mode,'i') as parameter_mode,
    coalesce(b.optargdefaults,'') as default
from(
        select
                unnest(proargnames) as parameter_name,
               unnest(proargmodes) as parameter_mode,
                regtype(unnest(proallargtypes)) as typeall,
                regtype(unnest(proargtypes)) as types
        FROM   pg_catalog.pg_proc
        WHERE  proname = 'your_function or sp name'
         -- AND prokind = 'f'
) a
left join(
             -- search for the parameter default
             SELECT
                     unnest(proargnames[pronargs-pronargdefaults+1:pronargs] )optargnames,
                     unnest(string_to_array(pg_get_expr(proargdefaults, 0)::text,',')) optargdefaults
             FROM   pg_catalog.pg_proc
             WHERE  proname = 'your_function or sp name'
) b on b.optargnames = a.parameter_name
where parameter_mode in('i','o','b') or parameter_mode is null
```